# mysql group by on certain condition and column value

Tags: php, mysql

There are 4 receiving methods. 1) delivery 2) pickup 3) mobile_topup 4) bank_deposit

if there are 2 mobile topups there I need only one. But, if there are 2 delivery methods then I need both f them. To achieve this, I have created this query:

```
$clause = "SELECT id FROM beneficiary_payment_info
           GROUP BY IF(ben_payment_method='mobile_topup', '', ben_payment_method)";
```

But, the problem is, it's group by with delivery methods as well. I don't want that.
Right now, I have `2 mobile_topup`, `2 delivery` and `bank deposit` in database.

I need `1 mobile_topup`, `2 delivery` and `1 bank deposit`.

I was just wondering that is it possible in this query or I need to do it in `php`?

**EDIT**

temporary, in `php` I have this solution. But, it doesn't look reliable.

```
$mobile_count = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($data); $i++){
    if($data[$i]['ben_payment_method']=='mobile_topup'){
        //unset($data[$i]);
        array_push($mobile_count, $i);
    }
}
if(count($mobile_count) > 1){
    for($i=0; $i<count($mobile_count)-1; $i++){
        unset($data[$mobile_count[$i]]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do something like this in a crosstab query, where you would get a count for each condition.

Comment: @JayBlanchard : I don't know, what is it? Can you give me an example or something? Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us your table configuration and some sample data? Perhaps a SQLFiddle?

Comment: I don't know, somehow `sqlfiddle` is not loading in my PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$clause = "SELECT id FROM beneficiary_payment_info
               GROUP BY IF(ben_payment_method='mobile_topup', ben_payment_method, id,)";
```

Comment: you could use a primary key instead of id or a field that has unique or auto-increment value